# BottomNavigationView not Hide when Scrolling RecyclerView inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, material-design

I did read others topics but not solve my problem.
I have a BottomNavigationView and 3 fragments. In one fragment I have a Toolbar/SearchView + RecyclerView (with cards) and a main BottomNavigationView.

The question is: In the fragment that contains a RecyclerView I need hide the Toolbar and NavigationView when scrolling list, I can hide the Toolbar but the BottomNavigationView I can't hide! And this block the lasts itens in the List.

Follow the code...

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/framePrincipal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/item_bot_navigation"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/item_bot_navigation"
                app:elevation="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_view"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/botNavView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_receitas.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_1"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchViewReceitas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewReceitas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Only this Fragment have a Toolbar/SearchView!

Comment: Hello, did you slove this problem? I get the same.

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll