# Hide/Show bottomNavigationView on Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have to hide bottom navigation view on up scroll and show on down scroll .how to implement this? 
my layout is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:menu="@menu/dashboard_slider_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have attached screenshot of view. Kindly check it.

[image]

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Add event/gesture listener on your list view / recycler view. Hide/show based on the event.

Comment: R u using RecyclerView

Comment: ya.. am using recyclerview

Comment: @KarthikThunga check my answer below

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Just add one attribute to `BottomNavigationView`

Material Library AndroidX

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 ....
 app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"/>
```

Support Library Version `28.0.0` or `higher version`

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
 ....
 app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>
```

> **Note**:- Your XML should follow the structure of XML given below in old answer.

**OLD ANSWER(Still Works)**

You need a helper class to do this .This solution works like [Google Material Design Guideline.](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)

Create a class `BottomNavigationViewBehavior`

```
public class BottomNavigationViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    private int height;

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, int layoutDirection) {
        height = child.getHeight();
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                   BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull 
                                   View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target,
                                   int axes, int type)
    {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull BottomNavigationView child,
               @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
               int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, 
                @ViewCompat.NestedScrollType int type)
    {
       if (dyConsumed > 0) {
           slideDown(child);
       } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
           slideUp(child);
       }
    }

    private void slideUp(BottomNavigationView child) {
        child.clearAnimation();
        child.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);
    }

    private void slideDown(BottomNavigationView child) {
        child.clearAnimation();
        child.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(200);
    }
}
```

For using this behavior you need to use cooradinator layout...

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kliff.digitaldwarka.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!---your RecyclerView/Fragment Container Layout-->
        <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        

         <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
             android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             app:itemBackground="@color/white"
             app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

      </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

      <!---NavigationView-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Add this code to your Activity that contains bottom nav..

```
mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomNavigationView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationViewBehavior());
```

Comment: @Abhishek Singh  If this FrameLayout is a Fragment's container layout， and the RecyclerView is in the ViewPager‘s item.How to make it?

Comment: @Zys..  It will work if you load fragment inside the frame layout.. actually I am doing the same... my frame layout is fragment conatainer...but  still if does not work then you can make `NestedScrollView` is parent of your fragments... and `recyclerview.setNestedScrollEnabled(false);` will work for sure

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Thanks !! It works fine. Do you have any hints on how to make the animation match the toolbar animation ? Or how i can apply the same animation to the toolbar ?  Cause I noticed that I cannot call setBahviour on AppBarLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: @AbhishekSingh how do you deal with the case, when the recycler view doesn't scroll cause everything fits on screen, but the most bottom cell is covered by the bottom navigation view. The bottom navigation would then never hide/disappear leading to the issue that the last row item is covered.

Comment: @Patric i think that time need calculation that how may item can shown or height of recyclerview<=screen heght and hide by code `mBottomNavigationView.clearAnimation();
        mBottomNavigationView.animate().translationY(mBottomNavigationView.getHeight()).setDuration(200);`

Comment: Its not working.. does it necessary to use DrawaerLayout as parent even I'm not using appBar.

Comment: @RobinHood its necessary to use `CoordinatorLayout` not `DrawerLayout` or `AppbarLayout`. Its working perfectly/

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I tried but no luck, this is my layout look like https://paste.ofcode.org/GCxZ5szY8gZjKh29DfNUJV, let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh thanks, its working fine for recycler view. Is there any way this can be done for listView also?

Comment: @manishpoddar actually it uses `NestedScrollView`.`RecyclerView` has `NestedScrollView` that why its working with Recycler but not with list. Any content with `NestedScrollView` this works fine but we cannot put list inside nested scroll its bad idea.

Comment: @RobinHood bro you framelayout is fragmentcontainer so fragment should contain recyclerview of Nestedscroll view to work.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh will you post your fragment layout which contain nestedScrollview?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh almost achieved but minor issue, I have 3 tabs, on 1st tab I scroll up and Navigation is hide and at the same time when I change the tab its also hidden over their.

Comment: @RobinHood put this code on fragment resume `getActivity().findViewbyId(R.id.bottom_nav).clearAnimation();
        getActivity().findViewbyId(R.id.bottom_nav).animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);`

Comment: How do we account for snackbars displaying above the bottom nav?

Comment: Even Bottom sheet not only bottom sheet but any views is not visible while using  Navigation behavior.

Comment: Consider overriding onNestedPreScroll instead of onNestedScroll (and dy instead of dyConsumed). onNestedScroll sometimes is not called while srolling fast.

Comment: I have the same problem with @zys when the Recycleview is inside a Fragment in ViewPager. But when the Fragment is alone it works fine.

Comment: @HoseinIT it will work fine inside viewpager. It may be code issue.. replace `framelayout` in above code with `viewpager` layout behaviour element should be define in viewpager too.. and view pager child fragment root node should be nestedscrollview or recycler view

Comment: Google are such dopes, they specify all these nice Material View animation standards but I can't find official guidance. Zero SDK support for these guidelines so you have to craft it yourself and can only find here on SO.. +1

Comment: @giulio Check out my latest answer. Latest support lib / AndroidX finally is helping to catch up with the design specs! No more custom code needed since this kind of `Behaviour` class is now provided and can be activated with a  single line :)

Comment: After roughly half a day struggling I got it working by simply adding that line layout_behaviour. The problem was that I was trying different combinations of nested layouts so here's the tip for those who use ConstraintLayout like me: The trick is to use a coordinator layout within a constraint layout. Hope it helps :)

Comment: WOW!! Perfect up to date answer. Should be upvoted as much as possible!!! Thanks for this app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/ solution!!! Perfect!!!

Comment: Does not work while having `CoodinatorLayout` as a parent.

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański your bottom nav should be direct child of coordinator... And scrolling components also.

Answer (score 18):

Try this,

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0 && bottom_navigation.isShown()) {
                    bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (dy < 0 ) {
                    bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

Image while scrolling up :-

[image: click here for scrolling up image]

Image while scrolling down:

[image: click here for scrolling down image]

Comment: How to hide bottom navigation when no element found. I am using Visibility GONE, but the problem is when scrolling on recycler view bottom navigation shadow display now.

Comment: Can you add the screen shot because normally it won't

Comment: Please look below this picture.

Comment: What if the recyclerview is in the fragment? And the bottom navigation is in the activity and there is only a framelayout above it served as a placeholder for the fragments.

Answer (score 12):

Updated answer **after the latest library updates**:

Hiding the `BottomNavigationView` on scrolling is now available with just one flag in the layout! Starting from version `28.0.0-alpha1` or the material/androidX `1.0.0-alpha1`.

I updated my project using the latter approach since the version now is a stable release candidate. **Update:** Use fully released version `"1.0.0"`!

The new out of the box available behaviour is called `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior`. Set it on the `BottomNavigationView` as
`app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` as described in the latest [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView).

Here is a full example:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

As with the hiding of the Toolbar on scrolling, you have to ensure that the content is a **class that supports the latest scrolling** like `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView`.

This ensures all is working as shown in the [animation](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1i9Bgvs2vzCMkB3xtehQ37j8ktbCIZbI6%2Fbottomnav-scrolling-1b.mp4) on the design specs

PS: `labelVisibilityMode` is another cool addition you get for free for taking the trouble of updating and that is described in depth in the [design specs](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior).

Comment: if in one tab I scroll up bar disappear(as expected) and when press back and jump to another tab screen - tab is still hidden, how to show it?

Comment: @Choletski i have the same problem and ask a question SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865536/how-to-show-bottomnavigationbar-again-on-navigate-back

Answer (score 12):

1. Update your project to Androidx i.e **Refactor >> Migrate to androidx** (Minimum Android studio version 3.4)
2. Using the default Bottom Navigation Menu xml file, replace the parent **Constraint Layout with  Coordinator layout**.
3. Add the line **app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"**

i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dashboards.Admin_dashboard_main">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <!-- Fragments Container -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_tenant_dashboard"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <!-- Bottom Navigation View -->

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_admin_dashboard_main"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
                if (dy > 0 ||dy<0 && csButtonLay.isShown())
                {
                    bottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
            {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                {
                    bottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `CoordinatorLayout` as a parent container and add the `app:layout_behavior`
in the child `View` and set the behavior `@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior`
this is the solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue working with the `Recyclerview`.
The attribute:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>
```

only partially worked for me, so I had to implement another solution.
I defined the `BottomNavigationView` inside the `MainActivity` so I had to set a couple of methods to animate it during the scrolling.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var animator: ObjectAnimator? = null

.
.
.

fun slideDown() {
        nav_view?.let {
            if (animator == null && it.translationY == 0f) {
                animator = translationObjectY(it, 0f, it.height.toFloat() + it.marginBottom.toFloat()).apply {
                    doOnEnd {
                        animator = null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun slideUp() {
        nav_view?.let {
            if (animator == null && it.translationY == it.height.toFloat() + it.marginBottom.toFloat()) {
                animator = translationObjectY(it, it.height.toFloat() + it.marginBottom.toFloat(), 0f).apply {
                    doOnEnd {
                        animator = null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `translationObjectY` is an extended function:

```
fun translationObjectY(
    targetView: View?,
    startY: Float,
    endY: Float,
    duration: Long = 200L
) : ObjectAnimator {
    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "translationY", startY, endY).apply {
        this.duration = duration
        interpolator = LinearOutSlowInInterpolator()
        start()
    }
}
```

And I finally create a custom `Recyclerview`:

```
class CustomRecyclerView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet?,
    defStyle: Int,
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    constructor(context: Context)
            : this(context, null, 0)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet)
            : this(context, attrs, 0)

    init {
        this.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    // Scrolling up
                    hideBottomMenu()
                } else {
                    // Scrolling down
                    showBottomMenu()
                }
            }

            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            }
        })
    }

    private fun hideBottomMenu() {
        (context as? MainActivity)?.slideDown()
    }

    private fun showBottomMenu() {
        (context as? MainActivity)?.slideUp()
    }
}
```

You can then implement it in your fragment like this:

```
<com.studio.mattiaferigutti.kamasutra.custom.CustomRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/searchRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add this in your xml

```
<BottomNavigationView
....
....
app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help somebody
read more:https://material.io/develop/android/components/app-bars-bottom

add
app:hideOnScroll="true"

inside BottomAppBar Like below:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>

    ...

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        ...
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        />

    ...

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code : when Scrolling down the Recyclerview to your fragment will hide the bottom navigation. then when Scrolled Up it will show the Bottom nav.

```
private View view;
private AppCompatActivity activity;
private ChipNavigationBar chipNavigationBar;
//...............................................

@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
         hide_NavigationBar_adwhen_Scrolling();
        }
        return view;
    }

//...........................................................

private void hide_NavigationBar_adwhen_Scrolling() {
        activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
        chipNavigationBar = activity.findViewById(R.id.chipNavigation);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
       recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) {//on_Scrolled_down
                //  chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(200).setDuration(500);
               chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(banner_ad_card_1.getHeight()).setDuration(1000);

            } else {//on_Scrolled_up
                 chipNavigationBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(1000);
                //  chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {


                if((scrollY > oldScrollY)) {

                        navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {

                        navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

        });
```