# Last item of RecyclerView gets hidden when using AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

At the second picture, items are scrolled till the bottom of the screen, part of the item is hidden behind BottomNavigationView.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation">
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_dynamic_recycler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:title="@string/title_places"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppbar"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppbar">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/header_text_layout"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="72dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="@string/my_location"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_places_toolbar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

Tried adding margin/padding to recyclerview - did not help. Did not find cases of AppbarLayout and NavigationView with similar problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try separating main activity part, like in main activity there should be CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout, Toolbar, FrameLayout, and BottomNavigationView. Then make that recyclerview attach on frame layout.

Comment: no need for relative layout in activity main file.

Comment: adding some margin will help you

Comment: Is there any was to avoid applying coordinatorlayout in each fragment of activity?

Comment: You don't need to apply coordinator layout at each fragment
simply use fram layout in all your fragments, I added answer below

Comment: @anandwana001 but the root element of frame layout is gonna be coordinatorlayout, which means I need to use it (along with same toolbar) for all fragment, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing this by separating things down.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/fab_margin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_dynamic_recycler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tool:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/theory_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="48dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to have Collapsing toolbar in a given fragment. Your solution forces all fragments to have CollapsingToolBar I guess.

Comment: Then you can go with your activity&dynamic_recycler but you need to give margin so that all views inside recycler view displays on screen.

Comment: Ended up using this method and hiding appbarlayout in the fragments which does not require using toolbar. Thanks.

Comment: If you find this solution helpful, could you please upvote it so that other people with the same problem can find the solution easily. 
Let me know if you have further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Set RecyclerView layout_marginBottom="110dp" because your AppBarLayout layout_height="110dp".

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Design Spec](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior) bottom navigation bar should hide on scrolling

Implementation : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/44778453