# How to show BottomNavigationBar again on navigate back

Tags: android, show-hide, bottomnavigationview

I'm using a `BottomNavigationBar` with `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior` to hide it when user scrolls down and display it when user scrolls up. This works great.

But how can i show the `BottomNavigationBar` again when it's hidden because user scrolled down and navigates back over back button?

At the moment my `BottomNavigationView` stays hidden.

I'm using support library `28.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somebody has a better solution for this, but for now i came up with the following.

In my MainActivity of my SingleActivity app i added the following function to simulate up scrolling:

```
fun ensureBottomNavigation() {
    if(bottomNavigationView.translationY != 0f) {
        val layoutParams = bottomNavigationView.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val behavior = layoutParams.behavior as HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior

        behavior.onNestedScroll(container, bottomNavigationView, host_fragment.view!!, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

In every Fragment of my app i'm calling this function in `onResume()` like this:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    // Ensure that bottom navigation view is visible onResume()
    (activity as MainActivity).ensureBottomNavigation()
}
```

Comment: Even better decision

behavior.slideUp(bottomNavigationView)

Comment: @EugeneP. Perfect solution.