# How to create a bottom view which is scrollable in some cases (not programmatically)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my xml layout, I have:

- a recycler view (height variable)
- a bottom button (56dp = H1)

Behavior expected:

- if recycler view height < (screen size - H1) -> button is fully showed at the bottom of the screen.
- if recycler view height > (screen size - H1) -> button is below and scrollable with recycler view.

I can do it programmatically.

Can we do it just using layout file?

[image: effect demo]

Thanks.

Comment: Is it like adding a footerView (your button) to RecyclerView when `recycler view height > (screen size - H1) `?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand your question? I want to scroll the bottom button when the recycler view touch it (when items change).

Comment: take a look at BottomNavigation

Comment: what about layout behavior for bottomNavigationView?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll