# BottomNavigationView does not show up when auto hide/show is enabled

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, bottomnavigationview

I've a single `Activity` with a `BottomNavigationView` inside of it's layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_home_bottom_navigation"
            />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My `bottom_avigation` changes `nav_host` `FragmentContainerView` with fragments. All of this fragments have `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView` and because of `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"`, my `bottom_navigation` automatically hides/shows on scrollDown/scrollUp.

I saw this question: [Hide/Show bottomNavigationView on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll)
. I'm currently using the answer given by **Abhishek Singh** but the problem is not this.

This is my problem: Imagine `FragA` and `FragB` both have `RecyclerViews` but `FragA` has less items causing that all items fit to the screen and not scrollable. Now when I switch from `FragA` to `FragB` and then scrollDown, `bottom_navigation` hides with animation and if I press back button I cannot see `bottom_navigation` anymore and because `FragA` is not scrollable I cannot make it visible by scrolling.

I've also tried `bottom_navigation.visibility = View.Visible` in `FragA` `onResume` event, but still does not work. I think that it somehow translates `bottom_navigation` to the bottom and because of that this code does not help.

So how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide/Show bottomNavigationView on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll)

Comment: @LaurentiuDaniel no, its just a solution for auto hide/show of bottomNavigation. I'm using it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. instead of changing the `visibility` property of the `bottom_navigation`, I wrote two extension functions on `BottomNavigationView` for hiding/showing it:

```
private fun BottomNavigationView.showUp() {
    animate().setDuration(200L).translationY(0f).withStartAction { visibility = View.VISIBLE }.start()
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.hideDown() {
    animate().setDuration(200L).translationY(height.toFloat()).withEndAction { visibility = View.GONE }.start()
}
```

Now in `onResume` of `FragA` I have this:

```
override onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    bottom_navigation.showUp()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no part from your code here my solution would be to listen on the back button:

maybe you can check this article it would be helpful

[Android: onBackPressed() for Fragments](https://medium.com/@Wingnut/onbackpressed-for-fragments-357b2bf1ce8e)

And there change the visibility for the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Thanks, but I've said that I tried that solution. visibility changing is not working