# Manage listView scroll with one item

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a listView that i need to show a bottom menu when it scrolls up and hide it when scroll down , i have

```
var mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0

        listView.setOnScrollListener(object : AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
            override fun onScroll(
                view: AbsListView?,
                firstVisibleItem: Int,
                visibleItemCount: Int,
                totalItemCount: Int
            ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            override fun onScrollStateChanged(view: AbsListView, scrollState: Int) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                val currentFirstVisibleItem = view.firstVisiblePosition

                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

                     this.menuView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE  

                    Log.i("a", "scrolling down...")
                } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

                      this.menuView.visibility = View.VISIBLE 

                      Log.i("a", "scrolling up...")
                }
                mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem

            }
        })
```

the problem is the listView has one item with a a textView that has long text , so there is no first and last items it only one item , hence above code always shows the menu as

```
if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
```

will be

```
if (0 > 0) {
```

Which is `false` , Any way to handle this case ?

Comment: Have you try finding it https://stackoverflow.com/a/44778453/5723796

Comment: @SagarThakarar this doesn't help it'a not a navigation it's a usual view