# How To Do This With Bottom App Bar In Android XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-components-android

This is my set up for BottomAppBar and it will hide if i scroll down, and show if i scroll up.
And I am finding syntax can show it by code. Is this possible ?
[Here is set up for BottomAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Ud8.png)

I read document , I saw some syntax like performShow(boolean) or performShow() on BottomAppBar from Android Developer but seem it did nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44778453/22058594

Material Library AndroidX

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 ....
 app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"/>
```

Support Library Version 28.0.0 or higher version

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
 ....
 app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>
```

Comment: I see this code just for behaviour of BottomNavigationView and I set that like the image I showed in my question